# How to get a list of objects by their id using an array of numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, dynamic

NOTE: I understand that the title is phrased ambiguously and the explanation below is simplistic, apologies I'm a little new to JS

I have this array of objects (this.listOfAnimals). I believe the purple represents the ids of each object.

[image]

I have a list of numbers below which are dynamically generated:

```
this.arrayOfNumbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5] which is set using:

while(this.firstNumber <= this.lastNumber) {
  this.arrayOfNumbers.push(this.firstNumber++);
}
```

[image]

I need to get a list of items from this.listOfAnimals with ids = the numbers in the array this.arrayOfNumbers. How can I do this?

For example, I need a list of all items in this.listOfAnimals whose ids are 0,1,2,3,4,5 (coming from the array in the 2nd image). All of the data is dynamically generated so I can't use hardcoded code like this.listOfAnimals[0].

Comment: The purple is just array indexes, not IDs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simplest code for array intersection in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript)

Comment: Ah in terms of the link, I'm not entirely sure but Barmar's answer below worked quite well for extracting the objects using their indexes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `map()` to iterate over `arrayOfNumbers`, and use the values as indexes into `listOfAnimals`

```
let selectedAnimals = this.arrayOfNumbers.map(n => this.listOfAnimals[n]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
this.arrayOfNumbers.map(id => { console.log(this.listOfAnimals[id]); });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have lodash in your project, [_.at](https://lodash.com/docs/#at) can do the trick:

```js
    const letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
    const indices = [0, 2, 4];

    const selected = _.at(letters, indices)

    console.log(selected);
    // ["a", "c", "e"]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```