# How to dynamically get a list of objects from an array using an array of values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, variables

I have a list of objects (called this.listOfDesserts):

[image]

Each object (this.listOfDesserts) containing the following:

[image]

I also have a variable called this.relevantColumns which is dynamically generated though a line of code like so:

```
this.relevantColumns = this.listOfCakes.summaryCakes.numberOfUsers;
```

The end result is always an array. As an example it could equal something like ['1305','1306']

How can I generate a list from this.listOfDesserts of all objects where the index (In the 2nd image I believe it's represented by the purple e.g. 1304,1305,1306,1307,1308,header,id) is equal to the values of an array (this.relevantColumns)?

In this example how would I be able to get a list of all objects in this.listOfDessert with indexes 1305 and 1306 without hardcoding?

Everything is written dynamically so I can't really use hardcoded lines like this.variableName[1304].

Comment: This looks very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64452333/how-to-get-a-list-of-objects-by-their-id-using-an-array-of-numbers/64452394#64452394). That was a list of animals instead of desserts, but otherwise the same problem.

Comment: Remove all images and put some data, this help to achieve a good the answer.

Comment: It's a similar problem but having tried the selected solution it only resulted in [undefined, undefined, __ob__: Observer]

Answer (score 0):

There are two stages.

One, obtain a complete dictionary of all the values

```
listOfDesserts = [{ 1: {obj: 1}, 2: {obj: 2}} , {3: {obj: 3}}]
listOfDessertsFlattened = Object.assign({}, ...listOfDesserts) // { '1': { obj: 1 }, '2': { obj: 2 }, '3': { obj: 3 } }
```

Two, map over the relevant columns and get the result from the array:

```
listOfDessertsFlattened = { 1: {obj: 1}, 2: {obj: 2}, 3: {obj: 3}};
relevantColumns = [1, 3];
result = relevantColumns.map((columnName) => listOfDessertsFlattened[columnName]) //[ { obj: 1 }, { obj: 3 } ]
```

Comment: I've attempted to use result = relevantColumns.map((n) =>listOfDessertsFlattened[n]) however it led to [undefined, undefined, ob: Observer]. I believe it might be because it's an array of objects where each object holds multiple objects: [ 0: {1304: {},1305: {}, 1306: {}] etc.].

Comment: If it's hardcoded this seems to work: listOfDessertsFlattened[0][1304], is there a way I can do this dynamically?